# DocumentList API and GAS. How to marry them?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

How about using this API?

developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list

It seems to be able to access the revision history feed.

But the examples are in .NET. How do I apply/use this API in Google Apps Script? Anyone knows how and can shed some light? Maybe a short sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look on the protocol for DocLists API. You can use this protocol alongwith URLFetch and Google oAuth
Here is a quick example, which returns the revision history in json format

```
//Get revison history
//resource_id is the id of the doc
function getRevisionHistory(resource_id){
  var scope = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', scope);
  fetchArgs.method = 'GET';
  var url = scope + 'default/private/full/'+resource_id+'/revisions?v=3&alt=json';
  var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
  var jsonFeed = Utilities.jsonParse(urlFetch.getContentText()).feed.entry;
  return jsonFeed
}

//Google oAuth
//Used by getRevisionHistory
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

To play more with DocsList API, you can see some more example on my Google Site
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth

Comment: Thanks for the response Waqar.

I have a couple of questions:

Is Resource_ID the document/spreadsheet key?
I want to connect to a spreadsheet by the way.

How do I invoke the function? Like this?

getRevisionHistory(spreadsheet_key)

Comment: Yes, Resource_ID is the key of Document/spreadsheet. To invoke the function, just call getRevisionHistory('spreadsheet/document ID Here') in your code. Make sure that the above to function are copied already as a separate in same project.

Comment: Thanks Waqar. 

I'll try it now.  Then I need to learn about parsing JSON.  No idea how to do that yet.  Thanks.